# Object instances share sub-properties?

Tags: javascript, properties, constructor, prototype

Given the following code:

```
var Car = function() {};

Car.prototype = {
  wheels: {
    rims: 'steel'
  }
}

var volvo = new Car;
var mercedes = new Car;

volvo.wheels.rims = 'aluminium';

console.log(volvo.wheels.rims, mercedes.wheels.rims); // 'aluminium', 'aluminium'
```

Can you explain why instance `mercedes` of `Auto` automatically inherits the sub-property definition for `rims` from `volvo`?

Note the following code works as expected with same setup:

```
volvo.wheels = 4;

console.log(volvo.wheels, mercedes.wheels); // 4, Object { rims: 'steel' }
```

Comment: Because `wheels` is a prototype property.

Comment: Every instance of `car` shares *the same* object `wheels`. Instance specific properties should be created inside the constructor.

Comment: Maybe the following can help in understanding prototype, constructor and mutating versus assigning members (in combination with prototype).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only ever create a single object for `wheels`.

You assign this object to the prototype, so every instance inherits its value.

Javascript will *never* automatically copy an object.

Instead, you should create the object in the constructor so that you get a new object for each instance.